# Android contraint layout wont hold lots of text

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently working in the contraint layout in android and the layout is tiled over and over again in a recycler view. When I constrain the textview to the left side of the screen with a margin of 8 dp, then contrain it with a margin of 8dp to an image on the right, I set the width to wrap content and the height so that it would just go down and make more lines as needed if the content was too large. The text goes past the image and sometimes even off the screen to the left and just completely ignores the contraints? Am I doing something wrong? The contraint layout is set to parent width and wrap content in height since it is tiled over and over in the recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text=" asdkjasdkjfasd sdafkjdsafkjasfd fsdkjsafdkjsafd"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/attk_logo"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Picture of layout in editor here http://prntscr.com/es6bhs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code with the TextView

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="asdkjasdkjfasd gdgh sd ds fj fg sj  gsdfjgj jsdf gsf j sdafk jdsaf kjasfd fsd kjsaf dkjsafd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484" />
```